# If $\sum a_n x^n$ = $\sum b_n x^n$, then does $a_n = b_n$ for all n $\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm thinking that since $\sum a_n x^n$ = $\sum b_n x^n$ are equal, then it should be obvious that $a_n = b_n$ for all  $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is this true or false? Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use $*$ for multiplication.

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856932/can-there-be-more-than-one-power-series-expansion-for-a-function

Comment: It's true when $\{x: \sum_n a_n x^n = \sum_n b_n x^n\}$ has a limit point.